# How to unlink the local package?

Tags: windows, npm, npm-link

I linked a locally developed package using NPM link command. Since then, I am not able to unlink it back.

I am on Windows 10.

I have tried:

1. npm unlink
2. npm remove
3. npm uninstall
4. Completely wipe out npm caches and global repo.

I would expect the package will be installed from the NPM network repo now, as I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "package": "^version"
}
```

in my `package.json` file, but it is still installing the local linked version. Where does NPM store links?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did `npm unlink` from the target directory and then `npm install` in the directory that has the dependence. Not sure if this is the proper way, but it made the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
cd $(npm root -g)
rm -rf <package>
```